# Location of Certain Location words

Tags: learning

I have a couple of Chinese sentences that I have been struggling with. I know basic grammar order: Subject, Time, Place, Verb, Object but I am unsure how to construct sentences of this nature:
ex. I want to have practice outside
I want practice to be outside
I want to practice outside.
In Chinese, would all of these questions be phrased the same?

Answer (score 1):

> I want to have practice outside -  我想在外面進行練習

*In this sentence, "have" is a verb "practice" is a noun.
"have practice" means "to engage in practice" which is "進行練習" in Chinese*

> I want practice to be outside - 我想練習在外面進行

*In this sentence "practice" is a noun object, "to be outside" implies " to be held outside",  which is "在外面進行" in Chinese*

> I want to practice outside - 我想在外面練習

*In this sentence "practice" is a verb, and "outside" is a  preposition & adverb, which is "在外面" in Chinese*

Comment: Thank you. Just one question- I have always learned location comes before verbs. Why does 想 come before the location words?

Comment: @Beginner  "我想 (I want)"  is the main phrase, "在外面練習(practice outside)" is the relative phrase, As you can see, in "在(外面)(練習)" , it does place the location 外面 before the verb 練習, If the sentence is just "我在外面練習" (without the verb 想), it would be a common sentence,  with location come before verb